# Optimization for routine repeatedly using FindMaximum

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I have a routine which repeatedly calls FindMaximum to find the local maxima of f[m,a,b,c] as a function of m only (i.e. considers a,b,c as fixed and then finds the values of m for which the function is a local max).

I know that the FindMaximum algorithm uses Derivative[1,0,0,0][f]. Does this mean that Mathematica will recalculate the derivative every time FindMaximum is called? If so,

1. Is there any way to avoid this (e.g. define explicitly a function equal to Derivative[1,0,0,0][f][m,a,b,c] and get Mathematica to use this function rather than calculating the derivative every time)?
2. If (1.) is feasible, given that I expect a run of the routine to call FindMaximum several thousand times, would it represent a significant time saving?

If it helps, the function is

```
f[m_,a_,b_,c_]:=(Exp[a(m-b)]+1)^(-1) - c(2+m)/3 + c ((1-m^2)/3)^(1/2)
```

and the routine calls FindMaximum twice for each value of the parameters a,b,c (starting at m=0.9 and m=-0.9 respectively).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FindMaximum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html) knows the Gradient-Option.

So you can just plug your gradient in like

```
FindMaximum[...,{...,...},Gradient->...]
```

I used your function and you'll get a speedup at about 23%. (For arbitrary choosen parameters and on my machine of course)

```
func=f[m,10,0,0];
grad=D[f[m,10,0,0],m];
Do[FindMaximum[func,{m,-0.9}];,10000]//Timing
Do[FindMaximum[func,{m,-0.9},Gradient->{grad}];,10000]//Timing
```

> {3.34375,Null}
>
> {2.71875,Null}